# Permission denied when running npm test via mocha on Travis-CI

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci

I'm setting up a simple NodeJS application which I'm integrating with Travis-CI. I'm using Mocha to help with my tests. However, while these tests run fine locally, I'm failing the tests when on Travis-CI before deploying to Openshift. Some help on figuring this out would be cool =)

**Travis-CI output**

```
CAT@0.0.1 test /home/travis/build/melvrickgoh/CAT
> mocha test/ 
sh: 1: mocha: Permission denied
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

This is what is have inside my **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js --websocket-port=$OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT --log-level=1",
    "test": "mocha test/ "
  },
```

Comment: Does the travis stuff have proper permissions?

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite sure where these permissions are found. Is there any place I can view? or a way to set it?

Comment: Standard file permissions, such as you set with `chmod`.

Comment: I've just used CYGNIX's chmod to set global write and executable permissions to my .bin file containing mocha.exe.

Unfortunately, my Travis-CI account seems to have stopped responding. I'll hang on and inform you if it works. I'm using Windows for dev here

Comment: Hi, my Travis build still fails even after setting permissions to global write and executable. 

/cygdrive/.../GitHub/CAT/node_modules/.bin
$ ls -dl
drwxrwxrwx+ 1

Comment: If you could post a link to your Travis build as well that would be great :)

Comment: Hi! here's a link to my Travis build https://travis-ci.org/melvrickgoh/CAT

Answer (score 12):

Same issue, adding this to my `.travis.yml` this fixed it for me:

```
before_script: chmod 0777 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

Comment: This is a bit anal retentive but if you're like me you'll use `0555` if not lower.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue on OpenShift when trying to run tests. Solved by making the the mocha file executable, as follows:

```
chmod 0777 /var/lib/openshift/53ef9c315973cabb00034c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, with mocha installed as a dev dependency.

I could solve it by simply uninstalling then reinstalling mocha:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev mocha
```

then

```
npm install --save-dev mocha
```

Maybe you could do the same for a global installation of mocha, but I did not test it myself.